# Conditional getServerSideProps

Tags: typescript, next.js

I want to dynamically enable, disable `getServerSideProps` using env varable. I tried doing this:

```
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONOFF === 'true') {
        export const getServerSideProps: GetStaticProps = async context => {
            const { locale = 'en' } = context;
    
            return {
                props: {
                    ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale, [
                        'common',
                    ]))
                }
            };
        };
    }
```

However Im getting TS error `Modifiers cannot appear here.ts(1184)`.
So how can I properly turn on and off serversideprops based on my env variable?

Comment: Move the condition to inside the body.

Comment: Why do you want to turn on and off server side props? What are you concretely trying to achieve.

Comment: @IndevSmiles I dont want to use serverside translations in some cases

Comment: Move the `if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONOFF === 'true') { ... }` condition inside `getServerSideProps` and return different `props` when it's not true.

Comment: to answer for OP: because there is a down side to using server side props. it comes at a performance cost, and you may have some statically determinable reason why you might want to turn it off.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
let getServerSidePropsConditional: GetServerSideProps | undefined

if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONOFF === 'true') {
    getServerSidePropsConditional = async () => {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    getServerSidePropsConditional = undefined
}

export const getServerSideProps = getServerSidePropsConditional
```